# How to add a dynamic widget area title

Tags: dynamic, widget, title, sidebar, area

I need some help with an issue.

I have a widget area on my home page with 4 widgets in it.
Each widget has a title, an image and a description.

I want to know how can I add a dynamic title for the whole area, above all the 4 widgets.
The title should be changed by the user in the backend of the widget area.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <h1>The dynamic title should be here</h1>
    <?php
        if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('utility-area') ) : ?><?php endif; 
    ?>
</div>
```

I hope it all make sense and thank you very much!

Comment: Are you using some CMS or what?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <h1><?php echo($someDynamicTitleYouveGotFromYourDatabaseOrWhatever); ?></h1>
    <?php
        if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('utility-area') ) : ?><?php endif; 
    ?>
</div>
```